# I'm looking for help editing a macro so that the next data set pastes below the data that was just pasted

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pasting data from multiple worksheets into one consolidated data tab and I want the macro to find the bottom of the data to know where I need it pasted.  What function do I use instead of Range to accomplish this?  I have little experience editing macro's, so the macro was writen by recording what I want it to do.

I was using the Ctrl shift down function to identify the bottom of the data set where I want it pasted but it looks like the macro won't adjust when there are more lines of data (Range A8626).  What command shoudl I use instead?

```
Range("A2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
        Range("A8626").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: `Dim lastRow As Long`, `lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`, `Range("A" & lastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`.